# Can I use hook_views_query_alter() to alter datetime?

Tags: 6, feeds

With Drupal 6.28, a client has pulled an ical ( with [parser_ical](http://drupal.org/project/parser_ical) ) feed using a Feeds Importer and wants a calendar display view. This is working just fine. Although the feed and server sit in the same city (and timezone), at some point, it assumes the iCal feed is a GMT and is recalculating for central time. Thus, appointments show up about 5 hours too early.

I'd love to automatically add +5 to those `DTSTART` and `DTEND` on import.

Where is the best place to do so?

1. Is `hook_views_query_alter()` the right approach?
2. Is manually editing the feed returned by [the iCal feed parser](https://drupal.org/project/parser_ical) module an option? It's "minimally
   maintained" and this install will live on Drupal 6 for a while.
3. Is editing the parser_ical/includes/ParserIcalFeedsParser.inc file that comes with the the iCal feed parser module a possible solution?

The ical feed starts with the following.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//SRC//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Chicago
BEGIN:VEVENT
```

A sample sequence would be something like the following.

```
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTART:20131001T120000
DTEND:20131001T160000
DTSTAMP:20130823T000000
SUMMARY:Fall Internship & Job Fair
LOCATION:Anytown, MO
DESCRIPTION:JOB CATALOG ONLHY AVAILABLE ONLINE! ....
UID:443535@domain.tld
TRANSP:OPAQUE
URL:http://...
ORGANIZER;CN=...
CREATED:20130823T000000
STATUS:CONFIRMED
LAST-MODIFIED:20130926T172212
PRIORITY:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
```